# getting an extra \ character in C

Tags: c

Given the string ptr, the output that I want is hi\\n hey \\n I am running linux that is why I have two slashes since linux treats a \n as \\n

is that rather than ending up \n in my in my final output(despite it being parsed as \\n) I end up with a \\n(which meant it was parsed as \\\n
My code :

```
char *ptr="hi\\r\\n hey \\r\\n";
for( i=0; ptr[i]!=0; i++ )
{
    while(ptr[i]=='\\' && ptr[i+1]=='r') /* copy all chars, including NULL at end, over char to left */
    {
        j=i;
        int count = 0;
        while(ptr[j]!='\0')
        {
            if(count==0)
            {
                ptr[j]=ptr[j+2];
                count++;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr[j]=ptr[j+1];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the error that I am having is
is that rather than ending up \n I end up with a \n

Comment: Your code would be significantly easier to understand if you'd indented it before posting your question.

Comment: sorry i was fixing it. any help with the actual question?

Comment: Just a nitpick: The fact that you are running Linux has no influence on how characters are escaped in your programming language '\n' in C code is always interpret as single newline character (ASCII 10) while doubling the backslash ('\\n') results in a '\' character followed by a 'n' characters.

Comment: `char *ptr="hi\\r\\n hey \\r\\n";` are they suppose to be newlines or actually escaped \ ?

Comment: leppie, once written to my file, that is supposed to look like hi\n hey \n

Comment: @junix: As nitpicking: Wouldn't `'\\n'` result in a compile time error or at least a warning?

Comment: ^I am reading from a file, Hi\r\n Hey \r\n , which C reads as Hi\\r\\n hey \\r\\n and all I want to do is get rid of \\r(\r)

Comment: @alk Forgive me. Of course it would be "\\n". At time of writing I though of ' more as a typographical indicator for a sequence as of syntax. But of course you are right. ;-) +1 from me for this

Answer (score 0):

That is because of your copying logic. In the while section after finding \r you copy j+2 to j and then increment j by 1. then you copy j+1 to j so basically you are copying the same character twice.

Try this changed block

ptr[j]=ptr[j+1]; changed to ptr[j]=ptr[j+2];

```
while(ptr[j]!='\0')
        {
            if(count==0)
            {
                ptr[j]=ptr[j+2];
                count++;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr[j]=ptr[j+2];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

For your case (ignoring the escape character and making it small) str = hi\r\n hey

when j = 2 it enters the while loop so 
Looping now

```
while(ptr[j]!='\0')
            {
                if(count==0)` - true`
                {
                    ptr[j]=ptr[j+2]; ` ==> str is now = (hi\r\n hey) (replaced \ at 2 by \ at 4`
                    count++;  `==> count = 1`
                    j++;   ` == j = 3`
                }
                else                  ` ==skipped`
                {
                    ptr[j]=ptr[j+1];
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
NEXT ITERATION

while(ptr[j]!='\0')
            {
                if(count==0) `- false`
                {
                    ptr[j]=ptr[j+2];
                    count++;  
                    j++;    
                }
                else        
                {
                    ptr[j]=ptr[j+1];  `==> str is now = (hi\\\n hey) (replaced r at 3 by \ at 4`
                    j++; `j==> 4`
                }
            }
        }
```

Thus giving you an extra '\'

Comment: can you give me an example, I don't understand how I was wrong

Comment: that is still not right. Now I have one slash at the end of \n, it looks like \n\

Comment: probably because you do not copy the null character to terminate the string?